# How to search an un-ordered list by just only pressing from keyboard in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

i've a list of a country made by ul li that is under a column of a table. I need to search the country when pressing key from keyboard.

```
<ul class="country-search">
   <li id="1">Country 1</li>
   <li id="2">Country 2</li>
   <li id="3">Country 3</li>
   <li id="4">Country 4</li>
</ul>
```

Sample here

[image: country list under the table]

need to search item on key press not typing on any input box..any help?

Comment: What class do you place on the element when selected?

Comment: This functionality is built into the `<SELECT>` object in HTML. You can set the `size` attribute to 20 and it would look just like the list you have. Could you use that tag instead of lists?

Comment: So you aren't searching for an input with autocomplete ([example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/autocomplete/index.html)) or for a `select[size]`? User should still interact with a form if he is typing something though

Comment: What happens next? Is the selction to be used as part of a form post? More data retrieved? How do you want to handle multiple countries starting with the same letter? If you are going to use consecutive key stokes, e.g.:  "Aus" how are you going to let the user know what they have types, and how are you going to let them fix it when the get a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the functionality you're looking for is built into the `<SELECT>` object in HTML, assuming you can use `<select>` that is.

You can set the `size` attribute to `20` and it would look just like the list you have. here's and example.

ex.

```
<select class="country-search" size="20">
   <option id="1" value="Country 1">Country 1</option >
   <option id="2" value="Country 2">Country 2</option >
   <option id="3" value="Country 3">Country 3</option >
   <option id="4" value="Country 4">Country 4</option >
   <!-- ... -->
   <option id="20" value="Country 20">Country 20</option >
   <!-- ect. -->
</select>
```

This is also very useful because you can use it as an input to forms.

**Update:**

If I'm understanding the OP correctly he wants something like this,

```
$(":not(input)").keypress(function(event ){

       /*Search the country for the letter typed*/
       var NotFound = true;
       if($("ul.country-search li").each(function() {

             /* If you haven't found a country starting with the key pressed check if this one starts with the same key*/             
             if(NotFound && $( this ).text().indexOf(event.which) == 0)
             {
                 NotFound = false; //Stop looking a country starts with this key
                 $(this).focus();  //Give this item focus
                 $("ul.country-search li").removeClass('highlightingClass'); //remove previous highlight
                 $(this).addclass('highlightingClass'); //Add highlight to current li

                /*do something else*/
              }
           });
   });
```

Comment: have you read the question? This is not so easy as you think by writing 2 more lines in html.

Comment: @Codegiant Check my update that might be closer to what you want.

Comment: @Codegiant I tweaked my answer to let you grab the exact `li` instead of knowing one exists in the list. This feels like what you asked for.